# How can I differentiate between a file being opened and a file being added while handling changes through Google Drive API in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api

I am trying to fetch the changes from a specific google drive folder.

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes

I am successfully receiving callbacks when I add a new file to the folder. However, I am also receiving callbacks when I click to open the file, which is not the intended behavior. I want to receive callbacks only when a new file is added.

To avoid receiving notifications when I open a file, I am using the urlArray as a workaround solution. However, this is not an ideal solution.

**I would like to know if there is a way to distinguish between opening a file and adding a file in the `drive.changes.list` response.**

```
let token;
const folderId = "...............";

// An array to store URLs of the newly added files in the Google Drive folder
let urlArray = [];

const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'];

const TOKEN_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'token.json');
const CREDENTIALS_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'credentials.json');

async function loadSavedCredentialsIfExist() {
  .....
}

async function saveCredentials(client) {
  .....
}

async function authorize() {
  .....
}

// Function to fetch changes in the Google Drive folder
async function fetchChanges(authClient) {
  const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth: authClient});
  try {
    do {
      const res = await drive.changes.list({
        pageToken: token,
        spaces: 'drive',
        fields: '*'
      });
      if (res.data.changes.length > 0) {
        const lastChanges = res.data.changes[res.data.changes.length - 1];

        // Check if the last added file is not trashed, belongs to the specified folder, and its URL is not already in the array
        if (lastChanges.file.parents && lastChanges.file.parents[0] === folderId && !lastChanges.file.trashed && !urlArray.includes(lastChanges.fileId)) {
          urlArray.push(lastChanges.fileId);
          const imageUrl = `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=${lastChanges.fileId}`;
          console.log(imageUrl);
        }
      }
      token = res.data.newStartPageToken;
      return token;
    } while (token);
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
}

// This function sets up a channel to watch for changes to a specific Google Drive folder using a webhook.
async function watchChanges(authClient) {
  const resource = {
    kind: "api#channel",
    id: uuid(),
    type: 'webhook',
    address: 'https://myDomain/webhooks/drive',
    payload: true,
    resourceId: folderId,
    expiration: '1680969600000'
  };
  const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth: authClient });
  try {
    const res = await drive.changes.getStartPageToken({});
    token = res.data.startPageToken;

    const response = await drive.changes.watch({
      supportsAllDrives: true,
      supportsTeamDrives: true,
      pageToken: token,
      requestBody: resource
    });
    console.log(response.data);

  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
}

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  authorize().then(watchChanges).catch(console.error);
})

// Handle the post request sent by the Google Drive API when a new file is added
app.post('/webhooks/drive', function (req, res) {
  res.status(200).send('OK');
  authorize().then(fetchChanges).catch(console.error);
});

app.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For google drive webhook, you can watch the `X-Goog-Resource-State` header.

> The new resource state, which triggered the notification. Possible values: sync, add, remove, update, trash, untrash, or change .

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/push

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when I open/add/delete the folder file, the headers always be this x-goog-resource-state': 'change'.

Comment: I just added the complete code

Comment: are we talking about fetchChanges or watchChanges?

Comment: What I said above is console.log(req.headers) from app.post('/webhooks/drive', function (req, res) , not sure is that correct?

Comment: Ok i took to liberty to look it up for u, and it seems that for years, this has been an issue. "add" will only appear when file is being shared, and any files added to a folder will reflect state "update". Hence the state is not exactly correct/unique. So this may be an issue for your application. " change" will be for anything else.

Comment: Thanks, when I use "file" and not use "change", it works.

Comment: @leojail may I know which part of your code u use "file" and not "change"? It's good for me to learn something as well.

Comment: I was wrong. so I just go back to using "changes", Here's the problem I meet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75977969/what-issues-with-receiving-multiple-file-ids-and-encountering-two-types-of-error