# What issues with receiving multiple file IDs and encountering two types of errors when receiving callbacks for new files added to Google Drive?"

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-drive-api

I am able to receive callbacks when a new file is added to the folder. However, I have encountered two problems:

1. I receive the changed file ID multiple times instead of just once. For example:

[image]

2. I receive two types of errors. I did not encounter these errors when testing locally using localhost, but after uploading to Firebase functions, the errors appeared.

```
FetchError: request to https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes?pageToken=515249&includeRemoved=false&spaces=drive&fields=%2A failed, reason: socket hang up
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1505:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:518:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:552:15)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1358:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
```

```
FetchError: request to https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token failed, reason: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1505:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:494:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
```

Here is my Code:

```
let token;
const folderId = "...............";

// An array to store URLs of the newly added files in the Google Drive folder
let urlArray = [];

const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'];

const TOKEN_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'token.json');
const CREDENTIALS_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'credentials.json');

async function loadSavedCredentialsIfExist() {
  .....
}

async function saveCredentials(client) {
  .....
}

async function authorize() {
  .....
}

// Function to fetch changes in the Google Drive folder
async function fetchChanges(authClient, savedStartPageToken) {
  const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth: authClient});

  try {
    let pageToken = savedStartPageToken;
    do {
      const res = await drive.changes.list({
        pageToken: savedStartPageToken,
        includeRemoved: false,
        spaces: 'drive',
        fields: '*'
      });
      res.data.changes.forEach((change) => {
        if (change.file.parents && change.file.parents[0] === folderId && !change.file.trashed && !urlArray.includes(change.fileId)) {
          urlArray.push(change.fileId);
          console.log(change.fileId)
        }
      }); 
      pageToken = res.data.newStartPageToken;

      initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      const database = getDatabase();
      update(ref(database, "/drive"), {
        token: pageToken
      }); 
      return pageToken;
    } while (pageToken);
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
}

// This function sets up a channel to watch for changes to a specific Google Drive folder using a webhook.
async function watchChanges(authClient) {
  const resource = {
    kind: "api#channel",
    id: uuid(),
    type: 'webhook',
    address: 'https://us-central1-something.cloudfunctions.net/app/webhooks/drive',
    payload: true,
    resourceId: folderId,
    expiration: '1681228800000'
  };
  const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth: authClient });
  try {
    const res = await drive.changes.getStartPageToken({});
    token = res.data.startPageToken;

    const response = await drive.changes.watch({
      supportsAllDrives: true,
      supportsTeamDrives: true,
      pageToken: token,
      requestBody: resource
    });
    console.log(response.data);
    initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const database = getDatabase();
    update(ref(database, "/drive"), {
      channelId: response.data.id,
      resourceId: response.data.resourceId,
      token: token
    });

  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
}

app.get('/webhooks', function (req, res) {
  authorize().then(watchChanges).catch(console.error);
})

app.post('/webhooks/drive', async function (req, res) {
  res.status(200).send('OK');

  initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const database = getDatabase();
  const driveRef = ref(database, "/drive/token");
  onValue(driveRef, (snapshot) => {
    const driveToken = snapshot.val();
    authorize()
      .then((authClient) => fetchChanges(authClient, driveToken))
      .catch(console.error);
  }, (error) => {
    console.error("Error reading data from the database: ", error);
  });
});
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: your watchchanges is a stream and cannot be used in cloud functions. You can only use the webhook.